# TemplateDoesNotExist atDjango deploy error

Tags: django, templates, deployment, pythonanywhere

Hope, you can help me. I made a django project (just in study) and trying to deploy it with djangogirls tutorial. Okay, it works. But! When i trying to go to my website https://anle93.pythonanywhere.com, I have this:

Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://anle93.pythonanywhere.com/
Using the URLconf defined in personal_portfolio.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
projects/
The empty path didn’t match any of these.

It's okay cause I havent any pages in all project. So. When i go to admin, it works(http://anle93.pythonanywhere.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/), I see username and pswd fields. AND when I try to go to my "projects" (https://anle93.pythonanywhere.com/projects/), i have this error [first screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXAoo.png) on screen. So, my project have this sctructure like on screen[screen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDKtk.png).[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDKtk.png). So the question is:

I understand, that django cant find base.html file, that extends project_detail.html and project_index.html, and this is the bs4 styles for all project, not for one this app I made, so, if i wonna make any additions like, for example "project_description.html" in new app, it will extends "base.html" too. Ofc, in localhost in works like as needed. I cant understand why it happens after deploy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What template dir configuration do you have?

For your structure should be smth like

```
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'personal_portfolio/templates/')
     TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR,],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: At now i just replaces base.html from project/templates/ to app/templates, and it works! But its not the right way.. Coz i need 1 base.html for all apps i can do int the future, they should be all in one style. So, what i did right now it's not right, but it works=) . what that i have there

Comment: TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ["personal_portfolio/templates/"],
        'APP_DIRS': True,

Comment: There's the problem, you shouldn't use relative directories because they cause problems when deployed. 
Change it to my what is in my answer above and it will work:)

Comment: yeah, it works! Thank you for help, but in settigns.py need to import os, withiout it dont work.

Comment: Im glad! Be sure to do the same for static files dirs and media dirs, otherwise you are gonna have the same problem!